# Add a value to a Pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I try to change the addr form an array but cant understand where my mistake is.

```
uint8 a[255] = {1, 2, 3, 4...., 66};
main(){
uint8 *testpointer;
testpointer = (&a + 32);
```

The Address form my a[] is 0x00000FC. And i want that the testpointer get the Address 0x00000FC + 32. But if i do it like in my code, it get a address of 0x000020DG.

Comment: Did you try `a+32`?

Comment: This isn't valid C. The compiler must give a diagnostic message saying incompatible pointer type. If it didn't, get a new compiler. If it did, listen to it.

Comment: `(&a + 32)` would give you a pointer 32 *whole arrays* further down in memory (had such a calculation been valid).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic honors the **type** pointed to.

`&a` is of type `uint8 (*) [255]`, i.e, pointer to the whole array, not a pointer to the first element of the array, so using that in the arithmetic here will lead to out of bound memory.

You need to operate on `a`, not `&a`. The array type, when used in most of the condition, decays to a pointer to the first element, which is the desired operand here.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is `&a`. That gives you a pointer to the *array* and not the first element.

The type of `&a` is `uint8 (*)[255]`, not `uint8 *`.

To solve your problem you need to use plain `a` as it will decay to a pointer to its first element (`a` is equal to `&a[0]`).